# How to enable automatic signing while publishing Nativescript app for iOS?

Tags: xcode, nativescript

I've run `tns publish ios --appleApplicationSpecificPassword uxm...`

**Error message says:**  To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.

But how to pass allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild while using `tns publish`

```
error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'com.cemkaan.sebapp' were found

Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 "No profiles for 'com.cemkaan.sebapp' were found" UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'com.cemkaan.sebapp' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'com.cemkaan.sebapp'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}
```

Certificates I already have

- I have Generated a Provisioning Profile for App Store Distribution.
- I have downloaded it and double-clicked file
- I have iOS distribution certificate
- I have identifier SebApp com.cemkaan.sebapp
- I do not have devices and keys